# Neural network cost is decreasing, but accuracy is not increasing at all

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I am new to neural networks, and I thought I'd try to make a neural network from mostly scratch in Python. I'm currently working on [backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation), but I am running into an issue where the cost does go down after each epoch, but the accuracy does not increase at all, and all of the outputs are completely uniform.

For context, it's training on a spiral graph data set, trying to guess what class of 3 a point belongs to.

I don't know if I implemented backpropagation wrong, or if it's just a stupid mistake. But here’s my code:

```
import random
import math
import copy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)

# Neural network layer class
class Layer():
    def __init__(self, num_inputs, num_neurons):
        self.weights = 0.1 * np.random.rand(num_inputs, num_neurons)
        self.biases = np.zeros(num_neurons)

    def forward(self, input):
        self.activation = np.dot(input, self.weights) + self.biases
        return self.activation

# Sigmoid activation function
class sigmoid:
    def forward(input):
        return (1 + np.exp(-1*input))**-1
    def backward(input):
        return np.exp(-input)/np.square((1 + np.exp(-input)))

# Mean square cost function
class MS_cost:
    def forward(output, target):
        output = copy.deepcopy(output)
        if output.ndim == 1:
            output[target] -= 1
            return np.mean(np.square(output))
        else:
            for i in range(len(target)):
                output[i][target[i]] -= 1
            return np.mean(2*output)

    def backward(output, target):
        output1 = copy.deepcopy(output)
        if output1.ndim == 1:
            output1[target] -= 1
            return np.mean(2*output1)
        else:
            length = len(target)
            for i in range(length):
                output1[i][target[i]] -= 1
                np.square(output1[i])
            return np.mean(2*output1)


class Neural_Network:
    def __init__(self, structure=[], act_func=sigmoid, cost_func=MS_cost):
        # Build network
        self.network = []
        self.act_func = act_func
        self.cost_func = cost_func

        for i in range(1, len(structure)):
            self.network.append(Layer(structure[i-1], structure[i]))

    # Forward propagate
    def activate(self, input):
        for layer in self.network:
            output = self.act_func.forward(layer.forward(input))
            input = output
        return output

    # Back propagation
    def back_propagate(self, input, output, target, learning_rate):
        dcda = self.cost_func.backward(output, target)
        weight_gradient = dcda
        bias_gradient = dcda
        for i in range(len(self.network)-1, 0, -1):
            dzdw = np.sum(self.network[i-1].activation)
            dadz = np.mean(self.act_func.backward(self.network[i].activation), axis=0)

            weight_gradient *= dzdw*dadz
            bias_gradient *= dadz

            self.network[i].weights -= learning_rate*weight_gradient
            self.network[i].biases -= learning_rate*bias_gradient

        dzdw = np.sum(input)
        dadz = np.mean(self.act_func.backward(self.network[0].activation), axis=0)

        weight_gradient *= dzdw*dadz
        bias_gradient *= dadz

        self.network[0].weights -= learning_rate*weight_gradient
        self.network[0].biases -= learning_rate*bias_gradient

    # Run training
    def think(self, X, y):
        for i in range(10):
            output = self.activate(X)
            print('cost:', self.cost_func.forward(output, y))
            print('accuracy:', calc_accuracy(output, y), '\n')
            self.back_propagate(X, output, y, 0.01)

# Calculate accuracy
def calc_accuracy(output, target):
    output_prediction = np.argmax(output, axis=1)
    print(output_prediction)
    return np.mean(output_prediction==target)

# Data set
def spiral_data(points, classes):
    X = np.zeros((points*classes, 2))
    y = np.zeros(points*classes, dtype='uint8')
    for class_number in range(classes):
        ix = range(points*class_number, points*(class_number+1))
        r = np.linspace(0.0, 1, points)  # Radius
        t = np.linspace(class_number*4, (class_number + 1)*4,
                        points) + np.random.randn(points)*0.2
        X[ix] = np.c_[r*np.sin(t*2.5), r*np.cos(t*2.5)]
        y[ix] = class_number
    return X, y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    brain = Neural_Network([2, 3, 3, 3], act_func=sigmoid, cost_func=MS_cost)

    X, y = spiral_data(100, 3)
    brain.think(X, y)
```

Logically, the cost function seems like it’s wrong and the backpropagation was implemented correctly, because it is doing its job and cost is going down, but I've run the cost function and everything seems OK.

So that leads me to think I've just made a programming mistake somewhere, but for the life of me I can't find it.

When I change the structure to [2, 3, 3], the cost actually slightly increases after each epoch, which means I probably made many major mistakes.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and change your title to [reflect the problem you're having with your code](/help/how-to-ask). Remember: you're not asking for you, and right now, you're asking "for you and every future visitor with the same problem, potentially decades from now".

Answer (score -1):

If you're working with a multi-class classification problem and using a softmax activation function for the output layer, the sigmoid activation function in the sigmoid class won't work correctly.

To fix the issues and make the neural network compatible with multi-class classification tasks, you need to make the following changes:

Activation Function:

Update the sigmoid class to implement the softmax activation function instead. Here's the updated code:

```
class softmax:
    @staticmethod
    def forward(input):
        exp_values = np.exp(input - np.max(input, axis=1, keepdims=True))
        return exp_values / np.sum(exp_values, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    @staticmethod
    def backward(input, output, target):
        batch_size = input.shape[0]
        grad = output.copy()
        grad[np.arange(batch_size), target] -= 1
        grad /= batch_size
        return grad
```

Forward Propagation:

Modify the forward method in the Layer class to include the activation function. Here's the updated code:

```
class Layer():
    def __init__(self, num_inputs, num_neurons):
        self.weights = 0.1 * np.random.randn(num_inputs, num_neurons)
        self.biases = np.zeros(num_neurons)

    def forward(self, input):
        self.activation = np.dot(input, self.weights) + self.biases
        return self.activation

    def activate(self, activation_function):
        self.output = activation_function.forward(self.activation)
        return self.output
```

Backpropagation:

Adjust the back_propagate method in the Neural_Network class to use the softmax activation function and update the weight and bias gradients correctly. Here's the updated code:

```
def back_propagate(self, input, output, target, learning_rate):
    dcda = self.act_func.backward(input, output, target)
    for i in range(len(self.network) - 1, -1, -1):
        dzdw = input if i == 0 else self.network[i - 1].output
        dadz = self.act_func.backward(self.network[i].activation)

        weight_gradient = np.dot(dzdw.T, dcda * dadz)
        bias_gradient = np.mean(dcda * dadz, axis=0)

        self.network[i].weights -= learning_rate * weight_gradient
        self.network[i].biases -= learning_rate * bias_gradient

        dcda = np.dot(dcda * dadz, self.network[i].weights.T)
```

Training Loop:

Adjust the think method to calculate the average cost and accuracy correctly. Here's the updated code:

```
def think(self, X, y):
    for epoch in range(10):
        total_cost = 0
        predictions = []
        for sample, label in zip(X, y):
            output = self.activate(sample)
            prediction = np.argmax(output)
            predictions.append(prediction)
            cost = self.cost_func.forward(output, label)
            self.back_propagate(sample, output, label, 0.01)
            total_cost += cost
        average_cost = total_cost / len(X)
        accuracy = np.mean(np.array(predictions) == y)
        print('Epoch:', epoch+1)
        print('Average Cost:', average_cost)
        print('Accuracy:', accuracy)
        print()
```

By implementing these changes, your neural network should be able to handle multi-class classification tasks and improve its accuracy over the epochs.

Comment: Is a 2nd answer really necessary? Or you should better edit & update your already existing one?

Comment: This answers, as with all 6 answers you've posted in the last 24-hours, appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: So this might be a dumb question, but why are you taking the raw output of the previous layer as dz/dw? if z is calculated by w1*a1 + w2*a2 ... wn*an +b,  for each neuron in that layer, shouldn't the derivative be an array of the sum of the activations in the previous layer? EX.) [sum(a(L-1)), sum(a(L-1)) ...] or equivalently just a scalar sum(a(L-1))?

I'm not sure why you are taking the raw output of the previous layer for dzdw, I litterally just started learning this yesterday, and I don't fully understand everything, so sorry for the dumb question in advanced lol.

Comment: @Ethan: *"shouldn't the derivative be an array of the sum of the activations in the previous layer"*: You are unlikely to get a response as this is probably the result of *blindly* inputting the question into [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) and pasting the result into the answer box. Or any response would probably be the response from ChatGPT. ChatGPT *can* be useful, but it is very unreliable and makes up stuff (which you may or may not have been subjected to here). On the whole, it is probably wasting everybody's time.